# R write.table in for loop - skipping first iteration

Tags: r, for-loop, output, write.table

I am trying to read a large dataset in chunks of 1000 observations, then split it by year, and write out a .csv for each year. The first for loop reads the data, drops unnecessary variables, and renames the columns. The second for loop says `if i == 1` write a table, all other iterations append this table. When I run this outside of the outer loop it works fine. However, when I run the entire thing the wanted .csv files (e.g. "test_data_year_2004.csv") does not contain observations from the first iteration. Additionally, it writes out .csv files, "test_data_year_4.csv", "test_data_year_5.csv", etc. It seems the unwanted .csv names are the last digit of my "years" vector. They only contain the column headers. I am not sure what is causing this error. I have a hunch it is the "years" vector. I will try converting the vector to string next to see if looping over as.character() works better. However, I noticed there is no thread related to this issue so I thought it wouldn't hurt to create one and see other possible ways of handling. Below is my code.

```
for(i in 1:1000){

  # Sequence to read 1000 rows every iteration and then skip rows that are read
  # Will read in total 1M observations 
  nrow <- (i-1)+(1000-(i-1))
  skip <- 1000*(i-1)

  print(paste("read =", nrow, "skip =", skip))

  # Will throw error when out of lines to read 
  data <- read.csv(paste(import.path, "test_data.csv", sep = ""), header = F, nrows = nrow, skip = skip )

  # Set variables to keep
  myvars <- names(data)[c(1:3, 6)]
  data <- data[myvars]

  # Rename
  colnames(data) <- c("hhid", "xcoord", "ycoord", "saleyear")

  # Subset data based on years - will have to iterate
  years <- unique(data$saleyear)
  # Drop first observation - it is variable name 
  years <- years[-1]
  years <- sort(years)

  for(j in as.numeric(years)){
    data.export <- filter(data, data$saleyear == j)

    if(i == 1){
      # Write initial file 
      write.table(data.export, paste(export.path, "test_data_year_", j, ".csv", sep = ""), append = F, row.names = F, sep = ",", col.names = T)
    } else {

      # Append
      write.table(data.export, paste(export.path, "test_data_year_", j, ".csv", sep = ""), append = T, row.names = F, sep = ",", col.names = F)
    }
  }
}
```